# specific version of python3 using venv

Tags: python, python-venv

How do I create a virtual enviroment with venv using a specific version of python on m1. I currently have 3.9.6 and I want a virtual enviroment with 3.10.
I create my virtual env using : python3 -m venv .

Is there a way I can specify the version, also not a fan of conda.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Comment: Already, didn't work.

Comment: `/path/to/the/desired/python/binary -m venv …`

Comment: Thanks, so that means I need to download the binary. I never had to use a higher version so am not sure how it.

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned, the Python interpreter must be installed beforehand and then a virtual environment can be created with `pythonX.Y -m venv path/to/venv`. Installing the Python interpreters is out of scope, there are plenty of resources available around to answer that question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have python 3.10 installed by running:

```
python3.10 --version
```

Then specify in your venv command like this:

```
python3.10 -m venv .
```

Hope this helps!